# Welche Verben bilden extrem viele oder wenige Wortformen?

Tags: verb, inflection, curiosity

Viele, die bisher nur nicht oder wenig flektierende Sprachen (wie Englisch) sprechen und anfangen, Deutsch zu lernen, scheinen anfangs häufig das Gefühl zu haben, dass jede Kombination von Person, Numerus, Tempus und Modus zu einer eigenen Wortform führt (oder zumindest führen kann). In Wahrheit werden viele Affixe mehrfach verwendet, d.h. die Morphe mancher Morpheme sind nicht unterscheidbar. Das macht es wiederum etwas schwieriger, analytisch die Kongruenzbeziehungen in einem Satz zu bestimmen.

Um Deutschlernenden den tatsächlichen Umfang von deutschen Flexionsparadigmen zu verdeutlichen, wüsste ich gerne: Welche Verben können die größte und die kleinste Menge an geschriebenen Wortformen bilden?

Die gleiche Frage gibt es auch für [Adjektive](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27924/welche-adjektive-bilden-extrem-viele-oder-wenige-wortformen) und [Substantive](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27925/welche-substantive-bilden-extrem-viele-oder-wenige-wortformen).

### Neben-/Methodenfragen

- Wie lässt sich die Anzahl automatisch zählen?
- Wo gibt es ein entsprechendes Korpus?
- Welche Formen sind ausnahmslos identisch?

### Bedingungen

Bei Verben, die sowohl stark/unregelmäßig als auch schwach/regelmäßig flektiert werden können, sollen beide Varianten gezählt werden (bspw. *buk/backte*), ebenso fakultative Umlaute (*du backst/bäckst*), Schwas (*ich back/backe, back!/backe!*) und Zischlaute (*du wischst/wischt*), aber keine ausgestorbenen Formen (*er backet*). Partizipien (*gebackt, gebacken, backend*) zählen zum Verbparadigma, aber die Formen ihrer adjektivischen Verwendung nicht (*gebackener, gebackene, gebackenes …*). Optional trennbare Verbformen sollen nur doppelt gezählt werden, wenn der Sinn derselbe ist (bspw. nicht *ich umfahre/fahre um*).

Comment: Kannst Du bitte getrennte Fragen für die verschiedenen Wortarten und für die größte und kleinste Menge an Formen stellen? Sonst wird das hier wahrscheinlich schnell unnötig unübersichtlich.

Comment: Die wenigsten Formen dürften Adjektive mit eingeschränktem Gebrauch haben, beispielsweise _quitt_ (1).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Sechs Fragen fände ich übertrieben, ich mache drei draus. Diese wird die für Verben.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Unregelmäßige_Konjugation könnte ein Ansatzpunkt sein.

Comment: Ich habe zu diesem Thema ein paar Fragen: Auch wenn ich die Frage grundsätzlich spannend und interessant finde, scheint mir doch die Zielstellung fraglich, was willst du wirklich erreichen? Ich meine was ist dein wirklicher pädagogischer Gewinn unbedingt das jeweilige Wort mit der häufigsten Flexion zu kennen, daß die Flexion das schwierigste überhaupt ist, ist doch wohl jedem Schüler nach der 1. Stunde klar?
Warum muss man diese Frage auch noch nach Wortart aufspalten?
Wie soll man Flexion automatisch zählen können, ich bin Informatiker und kein Linguist, finde aber jeden Hinweis spannend?

Answer (score 3):

Wahrscheinlich steht und fällt jede Antwort mit der Qualität des ausgewerteten Korpus und der Auswertungsmethode. Ich habe versucht, einer Lösung mit Hilfe des [**Vollformenlexikons von Daniel Naber**](http://www.danielnaber.de/morphologie/) (beruhend auf [**Morphy**](http://morphy.wolfganglezius.de/)) näherzukommen.

Leider enthält dieser Korpus z.B. von "backen" nicht die Form "buk" und andere Derivate mit dem Vokal "u". Daher ist das Ergebnis nur eingeschränkt tragfähig. Hinzu kommt der Aufbau des Lexikon: Es listet auf der ersten Ebene alle zulässigen Formen auf und zu jeder dieser Formen (bei Verben) die Infinitivform samt morphologischer Analyse. D.h. für eine Auswertung muss man erst alle Verbformen je Infinitivform zusammensuchen, was technisch ziemlich aufwendig ist.

Bei dieser Vorgehensweise stehen zwei Verben (mit 27 bzw. 26 Formen) an der Spitze, die wohl gar nicht dorthin gehören: "**wissen**" und "**müssen**". Die hohe Formenzahl resultiert daher, dass die grammatikalisch selbe Form teilweise sowohl mit scharfem "s" als auch mit Doppel-"s" geschrieben werden darf. Blendet man diese beiden Verben als Sonderfälle aus, stehen mehrere Verben mit 24 Formen an der Spitze: "**melken**", "**quellen**", "**schrecken**" und "**schwellen**". Dann folgt "**sein**" mit 23 Formen.

Anbei zwei Ergebnislisten: einmal zur Übersicht ohne Formenanalyse, nur mit Auflistung der im Vollformenlexikon nachgewiesenen Formen; dann mit zusätzlicher Formenanalyse, damit ersichtlich ist, welche grammatische Form jeweils nachgewiesen ist:

- 27: "wissen" - gewußt, weiß, weißt, wisse, wissen, wissend, wissest, wisset, wißt, wußte, wußten, wußtest, wußtet, wüßte, wüßten, wüßtest, wüßtet, gewusst, wisst, wusste, wussten, wusstest, wusstet, wüsste, wüssten, wüsstest, wüsstet
- 26: "müssen" - gemußt, muß, mußt, mußte, mußten, mußtet, müsse, müssen, müssest, müsset, müßt, müßte, müßten, müßtest, müßtet, gemusst, muss, musst, musste, mussten, musstet, müsst, müsste, müssten, müsstest, müsstet
- 24: "melken" - gemelkt, gemolken, melke, melken, melkend, melkest, melket, melkst, melkt, melkte, melkten, melktest, melktet, milk, milkst, milkt, molk, molken, molkst, molkt, mölke, mölken, mölkest, mölket
- 24: "quellen" - gequellt, gequollen, quelle, quellen, quellend, quellest, quellet, quellst, quellt, quellte, quellten, quelltest, quelltet, quill, quillst, quillt, quoll, quollen, quollst, quollt, quölle, quöllen, quöllest, quöllet
- 24:  "schrecken" - geschreckt, geschrocken, schrak, schraken, schrakst, schrakt, schrecke, schrecken, schreckend, schreckest, schrecket, schreckst, schreckt, schreckte, schreckten, schrecktest, schrecktet, schrick, schrickst, schrickt, schräke, schräken, schräkest, schräket
- 24: "schwellen" - geschwellt, geschwollen, schwelle, schwellen, schwellend, schwellest, schwellet, schwellst, schwellt, schwellte, schwellten, schwelltest, schwelltet, schwill, schwillst, schwillt, schwoll, schwollen, schwollst, schwollt, schwölle, schwöllen, schwöllest, schwöllet
- 23: "sein" - bin, bist, gewesen, ist, sei, seid, seien, seiend, seiest, seiet, sein, seist, sind, war, waren, warst, wart, wäre, wären, wärest, wäret, wärst, wärt

Hier die Auflistung mit morphologischen Angaben:

```
<ergebnis>
    <verb inf="wissen">
        <form f="gewußt">
            <m>VER:PA2:NON</m>
            <m>PA2:VER:GRU:wissen:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="weiß">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>ADJ:GRU:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="weißt">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wisse">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wissen">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:INF:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wissend">
            <m>VER:PA1:NON</m>
            <m>PA1:VER:GRU:wissen:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wissest">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wisset">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wißt">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wußte">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wußten">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wußtest">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wußtet">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wüßte">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wüßten">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wüßtest">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wüßtet">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="gewusst">
            <m>VER:PA2:NON</m>
            <m>PA2:VER:GRU:wissen:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wisst">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wusste">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wussten">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wusstest">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wusstet">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wüsste">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wüssten">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wüsstest">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wüsstet">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
    </verb>
    <verb inf="müssen">
        <form f="gemußt">
            <m>VER:MOD:PA2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="muß">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:3:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="mußt">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="mußte">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="mußten">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="mußtet">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müsse">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:3:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müssen">
            <m>VER:MOD:INF</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:3:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müssest">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müsset">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müßt">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müßte">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müßten">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müßtest">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müßtet">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="gemusst">
            <m>VER:MOD:PA2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="muss">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:3:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="musst">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="musste">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="mussten">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="musstet">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müsst">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müsste">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müssten">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müsstest">
            <m>VER:MOD:SIN:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="müsstet">
            <m>VER:MOD:PLU:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
    </verb>
    <verb inf="melken">
        <form f="gemelkt">
            <m>VER:PA2:SFT</m>
            <m>PA2:VER:GRU:melken:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="gemolken">
            <m>VER:PA2:NON</m>
            <m>PA2:VER:GRU:melken:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melke">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:IMP:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melken">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:INF:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:INF:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melkend">
            <m>VER:PA1:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PA1:NON</m>
            <m>PA1:VER:GRU:melken:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melkest">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melket">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melkst">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melkt">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melkte">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melkten">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melktest">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="melktet">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="milk">
            <m>VER:SIN:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="milkst">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="milkt">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="molk">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="molken">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="molkst">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="molkt">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="mölke">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="mölken">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="mölkest">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="mölket">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
    </verb>
    <verb inf="quellen">
        <form f="gequellt">
            <m>VER:PA2:SFT</m>
            <m>PA2:VER:GRU:quellen:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="gequollen">
            <m>VER:PA2:NON</m>
            <m>PA2:VER:GRU:quellen:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quelle">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:IMP:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quellen">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:INF:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:INF:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quellend">
            <m>VER:PA1:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PA1:NON</m>
            <m>PA1:VER:GRU:quellen:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quellest">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quellet">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quellst">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quellt">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quellte">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quellten">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quelltest">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quelltet">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quill">
            <m>VER:SIN:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quillst">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quillt">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quoll">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quollen">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quollst">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quollt">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quölle">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quöllen">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quöllest">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="quöllet">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
    </verb>
    <verb inf="schrecken">
        <form f="geschreckt">
            <m>VER:PA2:SFT</m>
            <m>PA2:VER:GRU:schrecken:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="geschrocken">
            <m>VER:PA2:NON</m>
            <m>PA2:VER:GRU:schrecken:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrak">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schraken">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrakst">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrakt">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrecke">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:IMP:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrecken">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:INF:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:INF:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schreckend">
            <m>VER:PA1:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PA1:NON</m>
            <m>PA1:VER:GRU:schrecken:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schreckest">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrecket">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schreckst">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schreckt">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schreckte">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schreckten">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrecktest">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrecktet">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrick">
            <m>VER:SIN:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrickst">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schrickt">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schräke">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schräken">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schräkest">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schräket">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
    </verb>
    <verb inf="schwellen">
        <form f="geschwellt">
            <m>VER:PA2:SFT</m>
            <m>PA2:VER:GRU:schwellen:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="geschwollen">
            <m>VER:PA2:NON</m>
            <m>PA2:VER:GRU:schwellen:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwelle">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:IMP:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwellen">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:INF:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:INF:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwellend">
            <m>VER:PA1:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PA1:NON</m>
            <m>PA1:VER:GRU:schwellen:PRD</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwellest">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwellet">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwellst">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwellt">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:SFT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwellte">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwellten">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwelltest">
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:SFT:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwelltet">
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:SFT:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwill">
            <m>VER:SIN:IMP:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwillst">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwillt">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwoll">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwollen">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwollst">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwollt">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwölle">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwöllen">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwöllest">
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="schwöllet">
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
    </verb>
    <verb inf="sein">
        <form f="bin">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="bist">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="gewesen">
            <m>VER:AUX:PA2</m>
            <m>VER:PA2:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="ist">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="sei">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:IMP</m>
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:IMP:NON</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="seid">
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:IMP</m>
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:2:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:IMP:NON</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="seien">
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:3:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="seiend">
            <m>VER:AUX:PA1</m>
            <m>VER:PA1:NON</m>
        </form>
        <form f="seiest">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="seiet">
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="sein">
            <m>VER:AUX:INF</m>
            <m>VER:INF:NON</m>
            <m>PRO:POS:NOM:SIN:MAS:BEG</m>
            <m>PRO:POS:NOM:SIN:NEU:BEG</m>
            <m>PRO:POS:AKK:SIN:NEU:BEG</m>
        </form>
        <form f="seist">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:2:KJ1</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ1</m>
        </form>
        <form f="sind">
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:3:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRÄ</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRÄ</m>
        </form>
        <form f="war">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:3:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="waren">
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:3:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="warst">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:2:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wart">
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:2:PRT</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:PRT</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wäre">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:3:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wären">
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:3:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:1:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:3:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wärest">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:2:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wäret">
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:2:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wärst">
            <m>VER:AUX:SIN:2:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:SIN:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
        <form f="wärt">
            <m>VER:AUX:PLU:2:KJ2</m>
            <m>VER:PLU:NON:2:KJ2</m>
        </form>
    </verb>
</ergebnis>
```

Comment: Darf man die Formen wie „mußte“ and „wißt“ in diesen Listen gelten lassen?  Das muss bestimmt ein Entweder/Oder-Fall sein, oder?  Entweder zählt „musste“ ODER „mußte“, aber nicht beides.  „melken“ oder „quellen“ usw. müssten dann zur ersten Stelle aufsteigen.  Was meint ihr?

Comment: @Jampot: genau auf dieses Problem weise ich im dritten Absatz meiner Antwort hin. ☺

Comment: @tohuwawohi - oops! Sorry. 

Comment: Also "wissen" und "müssen" dürfen nicht mit "ß" geschrieben werden, da in diesen Wörtern der vorangehende Vokal kurz gesprochen wird. Umgekehrt darf z.B. "rußen" ("die Flammen rußen") nicht mit "ss" geschrieben werden, da der vorangehende Vokal lang gesprochen wird. Ist eigentlich ganz einfach!

Answer (score -3):

Die Frage nach dem Verb mit den häufigsten Formen ist leicht beantwortet, das ist "sein". Quantifizieren kann man das mit dem Levenshtein-Algorithmus, in dem man die unregelmäßige Bildung mit einer hypothetischen regelmäßigen Bildung vergleicht.

Bei Google ngrams kann man sich die Rohdaten runterladen. Die Wörter sind teils annotiert, also etwa gehen_VERB. Mit einem Skript kann man dann z. B. Zeichenkettensuchen machen, d. h. "gehen" nehmen, suchen, wo das vorkommt und so umgehen, losgehen, vergehen etc. finden.
Ich habe gerade mal nach gehen gesucht und 411 Variationen gefunden; ein Problem sind allerdings die Rechtschreib-/OCR-Fehler.

Comment: _Gehen_, _umgehen_, _losgehen_ sind drei verschiedene Verben.

Comment: Auch daß _sein_ die meisten Formen hat, ist zweifelhaft; und was die Bearbeitungsdistanz damit zu tun hat, ohnehin. Falls du _mit den häufigsten Formen_ allerdings so meinst, wie du es geschrieben hast, hast du auch diesen Teil der Frage nicht richtig verstanden.

Comment: @chirlu: Mir war nicht klar, ob Du nun backen und überbacken als zwei Wörter + Rattenschwanz an Flektionsformen oder nur die Konjugationsformen der Grundform haben möchtest. Wenn letzteres, bildet sein definitiv die häufigsten Formen. Wenn ersteres, dann werde ich hinsichtlich der Methodik die Antwort ändern, auch dafür habe ich einen Ansatz.

Comment: Zumindest als Arbeitshypothese taugt die Annahme, dass _sein_ am meisten Formen bildet, durchaus. Wenn ich mich nicht verzählt habe, sind es 24 bzw. 34, wenn man _werden_ dazuzählt: _bin, bist, gewesen, ist, sei, sei, seid, seien, seiend, seiest, seiet, sein, seist, sind, war, wäre, waren, wären, wärest, wäret, warst, wärst, wart, wärt; werde, werden, werdest, werdet, wird, wirst, würde, würden, würdest, würdet_.

Comment: _backen_ kann hingegen mindestens 26 Formen bilden, wenn man die regelmäßigen und die starken zusammenzählt: _back, backe, backen, backend, backest, backet, backst, bäckst, backt, bäckt, backte, backten, backtest, backtet, buk, büke, buken, büken, bükest, büket, bukst, bükst, bukt, bükt, gebacken, gebackt_

Comment: @chirlu: Was das "Sein" angeht, hat Veredomon nicht Unrecht. Es hat nämlich die maximal mögliche Anzahl an Formen. Ich habe jetzt keine Lust durchzuzählen. In der Aufzählung von Crissov gibt es einige Fehler, beispielsweise sind "seist" und "seiest" die gleiche Form und es gibt bis heute Streit darüber, welches die korrekte ist. Ob gehen, umgehen etc. unterschiedliche Verben sind, ist für die Beantwortung der Frage vollkommen irrelevant, da es hier nur um die Endungen geht. Ich wüsste nicht, dass es hier ein gutes "Ranking" gibt, aber mehr Formen als bei sein gibt es nicht.Gleich viele möglich