# Welche Adjektive bilden extrem viele oder wenige Wortformen?

Tags: adjective, inflection, curiosity

Viele, die bisher nur nicht oder wenig flektierende Sprachen (wie Englisch) sprechen und anfangen, Deutsch zu lernen, scheinen anfangs häufig das Gefühl zu haben, dass jede Kombination von Kasus, Numerus, Genus und Steigerungsstufe zu einer eigenen Wortform führt (oder zumindest führen kann). In Wahrheit werden viele Affixe mehrfach verwendet, d.h. die Morphe mancher Morpheme sind nicht unterscheidbar. Das macht es wiederum etwas schwieriger, analytisch die Kongruenzbeziehungen in einem Satz zu bestimmen.

Um Deutschlernenden den tatsächlichen Umfang von deutschen Flexionsparadigmen zu verdeutlichen, wüsste ich gerne: Welche Adjektive können die größte und die kleinste Menge an geschriebenen Wortformen bilden?

Die gleiche Frage gibt es auch für [Substantive](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27925/welche-substantive-bilden-extrem-viele-oder-wenige-wortformen) und [Verben](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/welche-verben-bilden-extrem-viele-oder-wenige-wortformen).

### Neben-/Methodenfragen

- Wie lässt sich die Anzahl automatisch zählen?
- Wo gibt es ein entsprechendes Korpus?
- Welche Formen sind ausnahmslos identisch?

### Bedingungen

Da es einige Adjektive mit unregelmäßiger Komparation gibt (*gut, besser, best; hoch, höher, höchst*), erscheint es sinnvoll, deren Formen mitzuzählen. Ansonsten natürlich alle KNG-Formen der schwachen und starken Flexion (die gemischte bringt keine zusätzlichen). Einige (importierte) Adjektive werden sowohl unflektiert als auch flektiert verwendet (z.B. *rosa* vs. *rosanes …*); in diesen Fällen zählt die Höchstzahl an Varianten.

Comment: Es gibt keine  Unterschiede in der **Flektion** von Adjektiven, außer daß einige von ihnen (obligatorisch oder optional) gar keiner Flektion unterliegen. Nur die Steigerungsform kann unregelmäßig sein. Das Problem ist also nicht vergleichbar mit der Situation von Nomen und Verben.

Comment: Es gibt keine bekannte Statistik dazu. Schließanfrage "too broad" wurde ausgelöst.