# Welche Substantive bilden extrem viele oder wenige Wortformen?

Tags: noun, inflection, curiosity

Viele, die bisher nur nicht oder wenig flektierende Sprachen (wie Englisch) sprechen und anfangen, Deutsch zu lernen, scheinen anfangs häufig das Gefühl zu haben, dass jede Kombination von Kasus und Numerus oder sogar Genus zu einer eigenen Wortform führt (oder zumindest führen kann). In Wahrheit werden viele Affixe mehrfach verwendet, d.h. die Morphe mancher Morpheme sind nicht unterscheidbar. Das macht es wiederum etwas schwieriger, analytisch die Kongruenzbeziehungen in einem Satz zu bestimmen.

Um Deutschlernenden den tatsächlichen Umfang von deutschen Flexionsparadigmen zu verdeutlichen, wüsste ich gerne: Welche Substantive können die größte und die kleinste Menge an geschriebenen Wortformen bilden?

Die gleiche Frage gibt es auch für [Adjektive](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27924/welche-adjektive-bilden-extrem-viele-oder-wenige-wortformen) und [Verben](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/welche-verben-bilden-extrem-viele-oder-wenige-wortformen).

### Neben-/Methodenfragen

- Wie lässt sich die Anzahl automatisch zählen?
- Wo gibt es ein entsprechendes Korpus?
- Welche Formen sind ausnahmslos identisch?

### Bedingungen

Die Pluralbildung der Substantive wurde hier als Flexion, nicht als Derivation behandelt (obwohl ich inzwischen dazu neige, das anders zu sehen).

Die Motion (Sexus- und damit Genusänderung) muss bei substantivierten Adjektiven (*der/die/eine Deutsche, ein Deutscher*) und Pseudogenerika (*der Bäcker, die Bäckerin*) gleich behandelt werden und ich tendiere dazu, sie klassisch als Derivation zu behandeln und darum nicht mitzuzählen.

Das optionale Dativ-Singular-*e* wird mitgezählt, sofern es noch vorkommt. 
Bei schwankendem Gebrauch (*des Herzes/Herzen/Herzens*) werden immer alle akzeptablen Formen gezählt, aber keine poetischen Kürzungen (*des Herz’*), die ohnehin meist keine neue Form bilden.

Comment: +1 für "Morphe mancher Morpheme sind nicht unterscheidbar.". Ich google das, und frage meine Kinder beim Abendessen ab.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the topic is too special and requires general survey over all statistical linguistic research which is way beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: I wonder why the counter for closing this question is reset again although we counted it already up some months ago

Comment: Die Fragestellung - samt Unterfragen - ist gut und böte sich an für eine Doktorarbeit in Linguistik. Ob jemand im Rahmenb dieses Forums mal schnell eine Doktorarbeit veröffentlichen will?

Comment: Ich hatte die Frage in der Hoffnung gestellt, dass sie irgendwo schon beantwortet worden sei und die Antwort hier nur noch zusammengefasst werden müsste. Ich schätze den Umfang eher auf dem Niveau einer Seminar- oder Bachelor-Arbeit ein, aber habe mich – zugegeben – bei meinen eigenen schriftlichen Arbeiten im Studium gerne mal verschätzt. Antworten dieses Kalibers gibt es auf Stackexchange einige.